# Edits, When Adding to Geodatabase, Revert to Default in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, database

ArcMap 10.3.1

I have several shapefiles that I am attempting to edit in the following way.

1) Right click on shapefile -> properties -> add hyperlink capability to a field in the attribute table -> hide first two fields of data -> rename the alias of one field.

2) Change the color of the "point" icon to be unique for each shapefile.

Then I create a new File Geodatabase -> name it -> right click -> import ->  Feature Class (multiple) -> select all the shapefiles -> select my directory and save.

The problem is that when I open a blank ArcMap and connect to the new file geodatabase all the shapefiles maintain none of the edits I had made to their icon or properties.

I am attempting to send the geodatabase to a client so they can open it and be able to access the hyperlink and see the desired fields without having to go through and hide the superfluous field again or without having to tell the hyperlink field to accept hyperlinks again.

Is there a way to also export your changes to the data when creating a database?

Comment: you don't need to import to geodatabase. simply send the mxd with your shape files added to it, to the client.

Answer (score 3):

You can also go to `ArcToolBox > Data Management Tools > Package > Package Map`, in order to send your mxd packaged with all the layers. When your client gets the data all they need to do is go to `ArcToolBox > Data Management Tools > Package >Extract Package` and they should find everything as you saved it.

Answer (score 2):

Changes to symbology and layer properties aren't generally stored with the data in the database.

The easiest way for you to transmit that kind of information is to send along a map document (.mxd) with your database that your client can open up.  The formatting and property changes are stored in the map document.

You could, with some effort, set up the database so that the symbology information IS stored in the database.  This would be using what ESRI calls [Representations](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/008t/008t00000002000000.htm).

I don't know of a way to store hyperlink propeties other than by sending a map document.

You can set the alias of the field using ArcCatalog - just navigate to the shapefile, right click on it, and choose properties.  You can make the alias permanent on the 'Fields' tab.

Comment: for hyperlinks, i.e. feature attachments can be used.